# Performance issues for a keras 1D ResNeXT based network

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, profiling

I'm trying to use a ResNeXT type architecture to classify some pairs of 77 length signals. However, even with a relatively modest 38k parameters, the model is obscenely slow to run, at around 12 days per epoch of 60M training examples. Memory use also fluctuates up and down by ~10 GB which suggests something is going wrong with allocation and garbage collection.

I would expect a 1D model to be relatively quick, given that these models are usually applied to images of much larger size, and with many more layers.

I've tried profiling Keras with tensorflow-chrome, but only get empty output files. Is there something wrong with the approach I'm taking, and how can I effectively diagnose and optimize performance problems in keras models?

In addition, the model goes a bit crazy (taking up 100% cpu and locking up the entire computer unless CPU cores are restricted to 1)

Increasing the batch size from 5000 to 50000 makes the fluctuations in memory use bigger, and takes up all available (64G) memory). Decreasing it to 500 stops the large fluctuations, but estimates for training time are still in the 200+ hour range for on epoch.

Properly installing CUDA9 + cudnn + tensorflow-gpu decreases expected run time by around 2x to 100 hours per epoch. CPU load is still high and GPU load low but doesn't lock up anymore.

I've run other models with more parameters without any problems, so I assume this is something to do with this particular model's unusual structure.

Model code follows:

```
def relubn(b): 
  return BatchNormalization()(  ReLU()( b ) )


def resnext_1d( layer_in, n_in, n_paths, n_bottleneck, kernel_size ):
  paths = []
  b = Conv1D(n_bottleneck * n_paths,1)( layer_in )  
  b = relubn(b)
  for i in range(0,n_paths):
    group = Lambda(lambda z: z[:, :, i * n_bottleneck:(i + 1) * n_bottleneck])( b )
    c = Conv1D(n_bottleneck,kernel_size, padding='same')( group )
    paths.append( c )

  con  = concatenate(paths)
  comb = Conv1D(n_in,1)( con )  
  comb = relubn( comb )

  return relubn( add( [layer_in, comb] ) )

in1 = Input(shape=(77,2))

l1 = Conv1D(64, (9,), padding='same')( in1 )
l2 = resnext_1d( l1, 64, 8, 4, 9 )
l3 = resnext_1d( l2, 64, 8, 4, 9 )
l4 = resnext_1d( l3, 64, 8, 4, 9 )
l5 = resnext_1d( l4, 64, 8, 4, 9 )
l6 = resnext_1d( l5, 64, 8, 4, 9 )
l7 = resnext_1d( l6, 64, 8, 4, 9 )
l8 = resnext_1d( l6, 64, 8, 4, 9 )
ap = GlobalAveragePooling1D()( relubn(l8) ) # 64x1

out_class = Dense(28, activation='softmax')( ap )
```

Comment: 1. Keras is by design very slow for large models. (https://github.com/tensorpack/benchmarks/tree/master/other-wrappers). 2. It will be more efficient to use `tf.split` rather than to slice your tensor inside a for loop.

Comment: 1. Maybe, but by current day standards, this model is tiny.
2. I just tried tf.split, it does not make a noticeable difference.

Comment: @ppwwyyxx Claiming "by design very slow" is a very strong claim, not backed for your link.

Comment: Are you using a GPU? What batch size are you using? How much GPU/CPU utilization during training?

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro Yes I have a GPU, and assumed it was being used. CPU usage was going crazy, so I had to restrict it (see edit). Removing this restriction (or using maxcores=2/3) uses 100% CPU, while increasing(!) the time estimated to completion. Truly bizarre.

I just used GPU-Z to check if the GPU was being used, and GPU load is very low (<5%). Checking older models, it seems neither did they.

Comment: tensorflow-gpu properly set up, seems faster, but still slow (100h/epoch), and GPU utlization is intermittent and low in GPU-Z. How can I profile my model?

Comment: Your batch size sounds too big, use something like 32/64 and increase it until you get the best performance

Comment: batch size=64, estimated run time down to 17h per epoch. Still not ideal, and would still like to learn about profiling, but a big improvement. Thanks Matias.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever asking a question, it's best to include a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that people can start to talk about the same thing.

As for your case, it appears that the partial, not runnable example you provided does not include all the information. I tried to make a runnable example from your code: I copied the entire model you posted, and set batch size to 500 and total #example to be 60M. I used fake data. There is an error in your model (`l7` not connected to anything) and I kept the error.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import keras
from keras.models import Model
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras.layers import *
import numpy as np

batch_size = 500
nb_classes = 1000
nb_epoch = 200

X_train = np.random.random((batch_size, 77, 2))
Y_train = np.random.random((batch_size,)).astype('int32')
Y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(Y_train, 28)

def gen():
    while True:
        yield (X_train, Y_train)


def relubn(b):
  return BatchNormalization()(  ReLU()( b ) )


def resnext_1d( layer_in, n_in, n_paths, n_bottleneck, kernel_size ):
  paths = []
  b = Conv1D(n_bottleneck * n_paths,1)( layer_in )
  b = relubn(b)
  for i in range(0,n_paths):
    group = Lambda(lambda z: z[:, :, i * n_bottleneck:(i + 1) * n_bottleneck])( b )
    c = Conv1D(n_bottleneck,kernel_size, padding='same')( group )
    paths.append( c )

  con  = concatenate(paths)
  comb = Conv1D(n_in,1)( con )
  comb = relubn( comb )

  return relubn( add( [layer_in, comb] ) )

in1 = Input(shape=(77,2))
l1 = Conv1D(64, (9,), padding='same')( in1 )
l2 = resnext_1d( l1, 64, 8, 4, 9 )
l3 = resnext_1d( l2, 64, 8, 4, 9 )
l4 = resnext_1d( l3, 64, 8, 4, 9 )
l5 = resnext_1d( l4, 64, 8, 4, 9 )
l6 = resnext_1d( l5, 64, 8, 4, 9 )
#l7 = resnext_1d( l6, 64, 8, 4, 9 )
l8 = resnext_1d( l6, 64, 8, 4, 9 )
ap = GlobalAveragePooling1D()( relubn(l8) ) # 64x1
out_class = Dense(28, activation='softmax')( ap )
model = Model(in1, out_class)
model.summary()
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='sgd',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit_generator(gen(), epochs=nb_epoch, steps_per_epoch=60000000 // batch_size)
#model.fit_generator(gen(), epochs=nb_epoch, steps_per_epoch=200)
```

The speed of the above code is 2h/epoch on my machine, far different from what you reported. So you're very likely blocked by something else that's irrelevant to the code you provided. That's something you might want to take a deeper look.

As I mentioned in the comment, Keras itself is slow, so I translate the above code to its equivalent in tensorpack. The code then runs at the speed of 1.5h/epoch.

```
from tensorpack import *
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

batch_size = 500

X_train = np.random.random((batch_size, 77, 2))
Y_train = np.random.random((batch_size,)).astype('int32')
Y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(Y_train, 28)

def gen():
    while True:
        yield (X_train, Y_train)


def relubn(b):
  ret = tf.layers.batch_normalization(
          tf.nn.relu(b), training=get_current_tower_context().is_training
          )
  return ret


def resnext_1d( layer_in, n_in, n_paths, n_bottleneck, kernel_size ):
  paths = []
  b = tf.layers.conv1d(layer_in, n_bottleneck * n_paths,1)
  b = relubn(b)
  #splits = tf.split(b, n_paths, axis=2)
  for i in range(0,n_paths):
    group = b[:, :, i * n_bottleneck:(i + 1) * n_bottleneck]
    #group = splits[i]
    c = tf.layers.conv1d(group, n_bottleneck,kernel_size, padding='same')
    paths.append( c )

  con  = tf.concat(paths, axis=-1)
  comb = tf.layers.conv1d(con,n_in,1)
  comb = relubn( comb )

  return relubn( layer_in+ comb)

def tower_func(input, labels):
    l1 = tf.layers.conv1d(input, 64, (9,), padding='same')
    l2 = resnext_1d( l1, 64, 8, 4, 9 )
    l3 = resnext_1d( l2, 64, 8, 4, 9 )
    l4 = resnext_1d( l3, 64, 8, 4, 9 )
    l5 = resnext_1d( l4, 64, 8, 4, 9 )
    l6 = resnext_1d( l5, 64, 8, 4, 9 )
    #l7 = resnext_1d( l6, 64, 8, 4, 9 )
    l8 = resnext_1d( l6, 64, 8, 4, 9 )
    ap = tf.reduce_mean(relubn(l8) , axis=1) # 64x1
    out_class = tf.layers.dense(ap, 28)
    loss = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(labels=labels,
            logits=out_class)
    return tf.reduce_mean(loss)

trainer = SimpleTrainer()
trainer.setup_graph(
        inputs_desc=[InputDesc(tf.float32, [None, 77, 2], 'images'),
                     InputDesc(tf.float32, [None, 28], 'labels')],
        input=QueueInput(DataFromGenerator(gen)),
        get_cost_fn=tower_func,
        get_opt_fn=lambda: tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(1e-3)
        )
trainer.train_with_defaults(
        steps_per_epoch=60000000//batch_size
        )
```

The split operation I mentioned does not seem to affect speed.

My environment: GTX1080Ti; python 3.6; cuda 10; cudnn 7.4.1; tensorflow nightly build yesterday; Keras 2.2.4; tensorpack master as of Dec 19;

Comment: Thanks for the effort and catching the bug in the layers. After further inspection it seems my tensorflow was first ignoring my gpu, and is now refusing to use my GT730 GPU because of it's cuda capability = 3.5.

       Ignoring visible gpu device (device: 0, name: GeForce GT 730, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 3.5) with Cuda compute capability 3.5. The minimum required Cuda capability is 3.7.